# Exchange 2010 "Microsoft Exchange Transport" hangs every time

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, smtp, exchange-2010, windows-service

Our small network (1 server, ~10 workstations) runs Exchange Server 2010 on Windows 2008 R2 Standard; it has worked fine for years, but recently we cannot send or receive mail, though no error is apparent in Outlook; mail just ceases to arrive or be delivered. (External senders get a failed delivery notification after some hours.)

Disk space and memory look okay (store.exe uses ~90% of RAM but I gather this is normal and it will release RAM as needed); I see nothing of relevance in the Application event logs. Exchange Best Practices Analyzer shows no critical issues.

The Troubleshooting Assistant's Connectivity Test indicates that "the SMTP service and SMTP instance(s) on server MAT1 are started but the port did not respond". Further investigation shows that the Windows service "Microsoft Exchange Transport" is hanging (and due to the hang, cannot be stopped through the UI, only by taskkill). Rebooting the server fixes the issue briefly, but the service always hangs again a few hours later. How can I diagnose this hung service?

Comment: Have you recently installed any .NET Framework updates?

Comment: Yes, on 14 July there was an automatic installation of ".NET Framework 4.7.2 for Windows Server 2008 R2 for x64" (KB4054530): are you aware of any conflict with Exchange?

Comment: That update is almost certainly your problem. Exchange Server is not compatible with .NET Framework 4.7.2 yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe a windows update issue, refer to the following blog:
[Issue with July Updates for Windows on an Exchange Server](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/exchange/2018/07/16/issue-with-july-updates-for-windows-on-an-exchange-server/)

Comment: Based on that article, I rolled back and hid the updates KB4338823 and KB4338818. It seems to have fixed the issue.